When I test Connection from Google Tag manager "Test your website" fails but Events are being tracked and can see the data in chart why?
If Events are being tracked that why the Test Connection From GTM fails !!!??
I have set up Google Analytics 4 in My Web Site Created Tags and Events but When I test connection from tag manager it says "Your Google tag wasn't detected on your website. " 
But When I check in Analytics Site "https://analytics.google.com", I see there that Evens are being tracked as shown in attached screenshot

You are using https://127.0.0.1 for your local web site. It should be http://.
In most of the APIs you'll need to provide URLs with https (https://yoursite.com) or can provide http with only localhost (http://localhost:8800)/ 127.0.0.1(http://127.0.0.1) local addresses.

Thank you for your answer @Sathya and I've tried this as you've suggested but it still says "Your Google tag wasn't detected on your website"

can you make sure you are using correct google tagid in your website which you are configured in the GTM. @JeetRaythatha

I've make sure of that and even in inspect element I checked and it is loading the correct tags with correct ID !!

Here are the few more things you need to verify.

Make sure that your GA4 tag is properly set up in GTM.
Ensure that the tag firing conditions are correct and align with the pages and actions you are testing.
Ensure that the GTM container has been published after making any recent changes.
Disable any browser extensions like ad blockers or privacy tools and retest.
Ensure that the GA4 tracking ID in your GTM tag matches the one in your GA4 property.

